# User input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

How would I implement a text box in my program where users can type into. I then would like for my code's response(I know how to do the responding part) to be also present in the program. 
This code was recommended to me but it does not exactly help all too much.

```
    var inputStr="";
fill(0,0,0);
stroke(0,0,0);
noFill();
rect(50,307,300,40);
keyTyped = function() {
    if(key.code===8){
        delete(key.code);
    }
    else {
        inputStr+=key.toString();
        text(inputStr,55,335);
      println("keyCode="+keyCode+"  key="+key+"  key.code="+key.code);
    }
};
draw= function() {

};
```

This code only responds to keys pressed, not words typed. Not sure if there is proper syntax for that;
instead of

```
(key.code===8)
```

is there some sort of word or phrase way of putting it like;

```
if(word==='Hello'){
/computer responds/}
```

Comment: Are you looking for more of a real-time feedback on-type event type stuff??

Comment: Where is your html?  You should be working with an `input` elem somewhere here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
var textbox = document.createElement('input');
```

---

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"/>
```

---

Use [this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) site to find out the different key-codes and their correlations.

To use them in your code, do the following:

```
//key-code
if (key.code === 8){
   alert('backspace was pressed');
}

//text
if (input == "text"){
   alert('the input equals text');
}
```

So essentially the key-code input is the press of a key and the text input is the string of text that is entered by a user. In order for text input to be received, you must have a textbox as shown above in the 2 examples.

Answer (score 0):

To get the textbox's text, all you needs is to check document.getElementById('myTextBox').value

Here is a fiddle with an example of your desired effect
https://jsfiddle.net/t66b6ebL/1/

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='textbox1'/>
<p id='result'></p>
<p id='helloNote'></p>
```

SCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('textbox1').addEventListener('keyup',
    function(){
        var txt=document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
        document.getElementById('result').innerText=txt;
if(txt=='hello')
{
    document.getElementById('helloNote').innerText='you typed hello';
}
    else
    {
            document.getElementById('helloNote').innerText='';
    }
});
```